# How many times will we go through the deck before the island is sunk?

Tags: forbidden-island

In Forbidden Island, how many times will we be likely to go through the deck before the island is sunk?

I've tried to figure it out but I'm not sure how many Waters Rise! cards there are. I can see the water meter in images, so I could otherwise figure it out for different difficulties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Forbidden Island the treasure deck has the following breakdown:

```
5 each of the 4 treasures
3 Waters Rise!
3 Helicopter Lifts
2 Sandbags
```

Depending on the difficulty the Water Meter will begin between the 1st and 4th tick, giving you between 8 and 6 remaining ticks respectively.
This means in a game that you can cycle through the treasure deck between 2 and 3 times.

You can find a breakdown of the game contents in [the rules](https://gamewright.com/pdfs/Rules/ForbiddenIslandTM-RULES.pdf)

Comment: This is of course only considering losing due to the water level getting to the top mark, not losing by Fool's Landing being removed, treasure sites being removed before the treasures were claimed, etc.